# Getting a setOnClickListener error when I try to run this app

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery, button

I am trying to make a button link to a View class that i have made called drawing view the only problem is the app crashes and i get errors in logcat. If anyone has any helpful information on this problem i would appreciate it. Here is my code for the Main.class

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    DrawingView v;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        //LinearLayout layout1 = new LinearLayout (this);
        //FrameLayout game = new FrameLayout(this);
        //final DrawingView s = new DrawingView (this);

        //TextView myText = new TextView(this);

        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);



        //redCircle.setWidth(300);
        //redCircle.setText("niggers");

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //layout1.addView(myText);
        //layout1.addView(redCircle); 
        //redCircle.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //game.addView(myText);
        //game.addView(v);
        //game.addView(layout1);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //setContentView(v);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, DrawingView.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

and here is the logcat errors

```
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921): Process: com.Tripps.thesimplegame, PID: 1921
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Tripps.thesimplegame/com.Tripps.thesimplegame.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     at com.Tripps.thesimplegame.Main.onCreate(Main.java:49)
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
04-22 05:12:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1921):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.main);` write this before init/declaring `Button startButton`

Comment: what is this question has to do with javascript and jquery tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order from,

```
Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

to,

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
```

Make sure you have specified a correct layout in `setContentView` & check whether a button has id `startbutton` in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to implement this line correctly

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Implement in this way

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
```

Answer (score 0):

place

```
 Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
```

after

```
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
```